# Как определить тип/алгоритм/протокол кодирования данных?

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование

Имеется строка:

```
gGuL1fYofKnBO4NsZO8li91QRFBeI2Ou2Gar21kbdsVAq56M3d3iM/GZeYCkOWpzcLF3A2Dufo4XFNHW19lAyVCerGkgmsLgE4LCsKP81XbcoLVur3aqTAT2HCah5ARC
```

Похоже на то, что бинарные данные обернуты base64, но дальше тупик. Есть какие-либо предположения, какой алгоритм/функция шифрует данные подобным образом?

Comment: Откуда берутся эти данные?

Comment: Программа обменивается со службой

Comment: `{"data": "gGuL1fYofKnBO4NsZO8li91QRFBeI2Ou2Gar21kbdsVAq56M3d3iM/GZeYCkOWpzcLF3A2Dufo4XFNHW19lAyVCerGkgmsLgE4LCsKP81XbcoLVur3aqTAT2HCah5ARC",
    "version": 1}`

Comment: А вот ответ службы: `gGuL1fYqLaHweflor9VfcEPGw7STVIRKjfBZEOkhkHegbKbyr+8H98W7K57B3HnwRv3z1cIKzLV5UpIsX3giwNIneq21deqs`

Comment: Как видите, начало одинаковое "gGuL1fY", значит есть какой-то формат/алгоритм

Comment: То что сама строка - это данные закодированные base64, сомнений нет, видимо для избежания возможных проблем при передаче.

Comment: Что это за программа и что за служба? Т.е. опишите в тексте вопроса все известные вам прикладные аспекты, тогда может быть кто-то подскажет вам, что именно таким образом в  json передается.

Comment: Само назначение программы ни о чем не скажет, а вот данные - это обмен программы со своей службой лицензирования (запущенной как win сервис). Сразу скажу что никакого злого умысла нет, необходимо получать от службы только информацию о текущем ключе/лицензии (а конкретно сроке действия). Смысл в том, что мы используем её на более чем 200 рабочих местах и нужно автоматизировать учет активных лицензий, чтобы вовремя их докупать/продлевать.

Comment: Если это известный (не самопальный) сервер лицензий, то напишите его название еще и в метке под текстом вопроса. Это может привлечь внимание участника, который знает ответ на ваш вопрос. (Возможно его лучше было бы сформулировать как-то так -- *Как узнать срок действия лицензий, обслуживаемых  XYZ лицензионным сервером?*)

Comment: думаю, ещё лучше написать в компанию, которая производит эти сервера и попросить их о апи. Если за личензии платят, то скорее всего компания предоставит какой то способ получения этих данных (она ведь заинтересована в продлении)   Но что то мне подсказывает, что это продукт autodesk